# Stop R package build & reload from backing up and resuming R session

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

I am writing an R package in Rstudio on Windows 10. Every time I reload the package, a note comes up: "Backing up R session" and then "Resuming R session". This takes a bit of time (about 8 or 9 seconds out of a total package build time of 14 seconds), and it would be nice if it could go a bit faster. When I reload the package, I am most of the time fine with not backing up the R session and just starting with a clean session.

Is there any way I can stop R from backing up the session or resuming the old session? It still seems to take some time to complete the process even if I run `rm(list=ls())` before clicking "Build & Reload".

Comment: under global options, are you saving or restoring a .rdata and does disabling those help?

Comment: Yes, that seemed to do what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: 2020 and it still desperates me...

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, that's not a good solution for me. My problem is that if I forget to erase a large object in memory (an *output* of my code) before rebuilding the package, that object is backed up, taking several minutes, before my R session finally comes back to life.

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7287